# Django + React Ecommerce project [Stripe payment connecting problem]

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I've got a problem with Stripe connecting to my e-commerce website based on Django + React.

I've got an e-commerce website in that I want to connect Stripe as a payment system. My website has about 200 products so I want to create a system when [Order.TotalPrice] is taken to Stripe (ofc. from the server side) and Payment is done.

I care about the most trivial version of the code, because I want to add it to my website. I'aint a professionalist, so I really care of simplicity because of my skills. Thanks.!

Thanks, dudes a lot!

Comment: If you're looking for a relatively low code integration, I'd recommend trying [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart).

Comment: but there's a flask method, Can I edit it for a Django version?

Comment: The [`stripe-python`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python) SDK works in Django, yes. You'd need to adapt the code example I shared previously to work in Django.